# Class variables default value after super call?

Tags: typescript, class, super

Say I have some basic class that gets an object of properties and sets them in the class:

```
export interface BaseNodeProps {
  id? : string;
}


export class BaseNode {

  id : string;

  constructor(props: BaseNodeProps) {

    for (let prop in props)
      this[prop] = props[prop];

  }

}
```

And I extend this class to have more properties

```
export interface ExtendedProps extends BaseNodeProps {
  name? : string;
  list? : string[];
}


export class ExtendedNode extends BaseNode {

  name : string = 'Default name';
  list : string[] = [];

  constructor(props: BaseNodeProps) {

    super(props);

  }

}
```

Now, say I want to call for new ExtendedNode with some properties:

```
someProps = {
  name : 'My name',
  list : ['thing to do', 'another thing to do']
}
```

When I call for `new ExtendedNode(someProps)`, the object always get the default values (i.e. `'Default name'` and `[]`), although I sent different values to the construcor in `someProps`, that the `super()` method should set. Does the super() command is being called before the variables declaration? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Post code that compiles. Among other things, you're calling super() instead of super(props)

Comment: Sorry, you right, fixed it to super(props). The question still remains

Comment: Yes, the super call is what happens first. Because in order to be an ExtendedNode you first need to be a BaseNode. The child constructor must be able to reference properties and methods defined in the base class

Comment: Thanks! so I guess the for loop in the BaseNode is kind of meaningless (in this case), and I need to write it in the constructor of every extended class if I want the input props will override the default values, or alternatively set the default values inside the constructor

Comment: The base class constructor shouldn't initialize properties defined in the subclass. You shouldn't have a loop in the first place, but should only initialize the properties that are actually declared.